# Fill in radio input with database data

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

When I query the form returns the input radio filled with the data of the database, as shown:

```
<input type="radio" id="Estado" name="Estado" value="Pendente" ' . ( ($row6["Estado"]=='Pendente') ? 'checked' : '' ) .' readonly="true"> Pendente &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="radio" id="Estado" name="Estado" value="Concluído" ' . ( ($row6["Estado"]=='Concluído') ? 'checked' : '' ) .' readonly="true"> Concluído
```

I also show in the completed image:

[image]

But when I click the edit button it changes the filled input radio and should not, because it no longer fills according to the data of the database, as I show in the image:
[image]

script:

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit_data6', function(){  
           var employee_id6 = $(this).attr("Id");  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"./fetch26",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{employee_id6:employee_id6},  
                dataType:"json",  
                success:function(data){ 

                     $('#data6').val(data.data6);
                     $('#Colaborador6').val(data.Colaborador6); 
                     $('#Observacao6').val(data.Observacao6);
                     $('#Estado1').prop("checked", data.Estado);
                     $('#Conclusao').val(data.Conclusao);
                     $('#employee_id6').val(data.Id6);
                     $('#insert6').val("Gravar");                    
                     $('#exampleModal6').modal('show');              
                }  
           });  
      });  

      $('#insert_form6').on("submit", function(event){  
           event.preventDefault(); 
           if($('#Colaborador6').val() == "")  
           {  
                alert("Colaborador é necessário");  
           }           
           else  
           {  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:".conexao26",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data:$('#insert_form6').serialize()
                     ,  
                     beforeSend:function(){  

                          $('#insert6').val("Inserting");  
                     },

                     success:function(data){                     

                          $('#insert_form6')[0].reset();  
                          $('#exampleModal6').modal('hide');  
                          $('#employee_table').html(data); 
                          location.reload("exampleModal6");
                     }  
                });  
           }  
      });
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" id="insert_form6">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <h6><label for="Data-name" class="col-form-label">Data</label></h6>
            <h6><input type="date" name="data6" id="data6" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>"></h6>
          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <h6><label for="Colaborador-text" class="col-form-label">Colaborador</label></h6>
            <h6><select style="width:150px" name="Colaborador6" id="Colaborador6" required>

<option></option>

<?php

$sql = "SELECT Funcionario FROM centrodb.InfoLuvas WHERE Ativo = '1' AND Funcao = 'Limpeza' AND Valencia = 'LAR'";
$qr = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($ln = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr)){
  echo '<option value="'.$ln['Funcionario'].'">'.$ln['Funcionario'].'</option>';
}
?>
</select></h6>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
         </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <h6><label for="Observacao-name" class="col-form-label">Tarefa Pendente</label></h6>
            <textarea type="text" id="Observacao6" name="Observacao6" class="form-control"></textarea>
          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
          <h6><label for="Observacao-name" class="col-form-label">Estado</label></h6> 
          <div style="clear:both;"></div>
          <h6><input type="radio" id="Estado1" name="Estado" value="Pendente"> Pendente &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="radio" id="Estado1" name="Estado" value="Concluido"> Concluído</h6> 
          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
         </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
            <div class="disabled form-group">
            <h6><label for="Observacao-name" class="col-form-label">Conclusão</label></h6>
            <textarea type="text" id="Conclusao" name="Conclusao" class="form-control"></textarea>
          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
          <div class="form-group">
          <h6><input type="hidden" name="Nome6" id="Nome6" value="Ana Ribeiro" readonly="true"></h6>
          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
          <div class="form-group">
          <h6><input type="hidden" name="NomeConc" id="NomeConc" value="Ana Ribeiro" readonly="true"></h6>
          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Sair</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="employee_id6" id="employee_id6" />
        <input type="submit" name="insert6" id="insert6" value="Registo" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-success" /> 
      </div>
        </form>
```

**I'm trying these ways but I still do not solve the problem:**

1st form:

```
var tipo_conta = $('.tipo_conta').val(data.Estado);

if(tipo_conta == 'Pendente'){

  $('#Estado1').prop('checked' , true);

}else{ 

  $('#Estado2').prop('checked' ,true);

}
```

2st form:

```
var radios = document.getElementsByName("Estado");

if (radios.value == "Pendente") {
            radios.checked = true;
        }else{
            radios.checked = true;
        }
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: It looks like both of you radio inputs are using the same id: "Estado1." The ID property needs to be unique for each element. This is likely the reason you are not getting the intended result. This line needs changed along with the ID change -> $('#Estado1').prop("checked", data.Estado);

Comment: Could you add html code?

Comment: @Mayur I added the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I created the variable `lis` to receive the value that the `radio input` receives from the database:

```
var lis = $("#Estado").val();
```

Then inside the `data` function I created another variable with the value that the `radio input` receives from the function:

```
var teste = data.Estado;
```

and finally I check with `if`:

```
if(lis == teste){
$('#Estado').prop('checked' , true);
}else{ 
$('#Estado1').prop('checked' ,true);
}
```

Full Code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit_data6', function(){  
           var employee_id6 = $(this).attr("Id");
           var lis = $("#Estado").val();
           $.ajax({  
                url:"./fetch26",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{employee_id6:employee_id6},  
                dataType:"json",  
                success:function(data){
                  var teste = data.Estado;
                     $('#data6').val(data.data6);
                     $('#Colaborador6').val(data.Colaborador6); 
                     $('#Observacao6').val(data.Observacao6);
                     if(lis == teste){
                     $('#Estado').prop('checked' , true);
                     }else{ 
                     $('#Estado1').prop('checked' ,true);
                     } 
                     $('#Conclusao').val(data.Conclusao);
                     $('#employee_id6').val(data.Id6);
                     $('#insert6').val("Gravar");                    
                     $('#exampleModal6').modal('show'); 

                }  
           });  
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue inside the HTML file. As @daddygames suggested you have used the same ID in both Radio button. see below

```
<h6>
    <input type="radio" id="Estado1" name="Estado" value="Pendente"> Pendente &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
    <input type="radio" id="Estado1" name="Estado" value="Concluido"> Concluído
</h6>
```

An ID must be unique. Update the ID and make it unique. Then change the code in `.ajax` script according to your need. This will help you.

Comment: Okay, I've already corrected the ID's problem, but how do I change Ajax now?

Comment: Don't change both radio button's ID. Just change first one's (`<input type="radio" id="Estado1" name="Estado" value="Pendente">`). Then there is no need to change  `ajax`. @Bruno

Comment: You are saying to only change the ID of the first one this way: <input type="radio" id="Estado2" name="Estado" value="Pendente">

Comment: Yes exactly the same.

Comment: I changed the Id of the first radio input but continue to change the radius by clicking the edit button

Comment: Can you please explain more?

Comment: When you return from the completed database and then click edit it maintains the correct padding. But when Pending returns I click on edit switch to complete. I changed only the input ID of the first radio as

Comment: The problem is that Ajax does not check which input of the radios it has to fill, it has to fill in according to the value that returns from the table, if Pending fills the pending if Completed fills the completed

Comment: You must have to code accordingly. I show you the main issue of your html code.

Comment: And I solved the IDS problem. Now the problem of not filling the input radio according to the database, I think it is because it does not check in ajax which of the inputs it has to fill according to the abse data.

Comment: I added to the question what I am trying but it is not working